# MEQP1 possible error list for Magento1

Tags: magento-1, coding-standards

Can anyone give me solution for these warnings.

> Model LSD method load() detected in loop

```
$item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

> Data load getFirstItem() method detected in loop

```
$attribute=Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', $data['attribute_id'])->getFirstItem();
```

> Array size calculation function count() detected in loop

```
$pidsCount=count($pids);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Model LSD method load() detected in loop

This is quite explicit. Basically you're calling a `load()` method in a loop like:

```
for() {
    $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
}
```

It's pretty bad in terms of performance and you shouldn't do that. Depending on the reason you're doing it you'll have to refactor your code.

```
Data load getFirstItem() method detected in loop
```

Same here, on top of that you need to limit your collection when using `getFirstItem()`

```
$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', $data['attribute_id'])->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1)->getFirstItem();

Array size calculation function count() detected in loop
```

Same here, you're counting in a loop, depending on your needs you need to refactor.

Unfortunately, looking at pieces of code does not help in your case because without the full scope of the code it's hard to tell what / how to refactor.

Comment: can i ignore these warning?

Comment: @QaisarSatti yes totally. I think the marketplace only reject extensions when errors of severity 8 or more are being trigerred

Comment: @QaisarSatti my bad actually the extension is rejected only when triggering errors of severity 10: http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/review-code-validation.html